# XSL Help required

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Hello
Am a beginner to XSL hardly know few commands.
I was trying out a sample where i have to format a number based on the entry in the XML.
I want to use the format-number function to achieve the same.

```
<Details>
<Order>Bulk Order</Order>
<OrderDate>1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00</OrderDate>
<Quantity>100</Quantity>
<Price>99.45</Price>
<Format>de_DE</Format>
</Details>


<Details>
<Order>Bulk Order</Order>
<OrderDate>1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00</OrderDate>
<Quantity>100</Quantity>
<Price>99.45</Price>
<Format>en_US</Format>
</Details>
```

However i can render the output if i use :

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(500100, "###,###.00")' />
```

But i want to use a certain condition

i.e if the Format is de_DE :
I want to pass the ###.###,00 to format-number method (note the decimal and thousand separators)
or if the Format is en_US
I want to pass the ###,###.00 to format-number method

I hopeless tried using choose statement ( but i really have no idea about the syntax of usage)

```
<xslt:choose>
    <xslt:when test="$format = 'de_DE'">###,###.00</xslt:when>
    <xslt:when test="$format = 'en_US'">###.###,00</xslt:when>
    <xslt:otherwise>###.###,00</xslt:otherwise>
</xslt:choose>
```

Can anyone help me to put this onto a template or something so that i just call

and i get the output based on the format present in the XML

Thanks
Srivatsa

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the best, truly XSLT solution. Feel free to accept my answer :)

Comment: @@this-Me: Isn't it high time to *accept* the best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply-templates and match on the value of the text node as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">


<xsl:template match="/">        
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Details"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Details">      

    <xsl:variable name="total" select="Price * Quantity"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="Format">
        <xsl:with-param name="total" select="$total"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Format[text()='de_DE']">
    <xsl:param name="total"/>       
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($total, '###.###.00')"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Format[text()='en_US']">
    <xsl:param name="total"/>       
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($total, '###,###.00')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This code for example, matches all Details nodes and for each match gets the total for the order. It then does an apply-template on the format passing in the total as a parameter. The match then occurs on the value of the format node.

I think the format '###.###.00' is invalid as it seems that only one decimal point is allowed. '###,###.00' is fine.

Answer (score 4):

**XSLT has the [`<xsl:decimal-format>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#format-number) directive especially for this case**.

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:decimal-format name="de_DE" decimal-separator="." grouping-separator="," />
 <xsl:decimal-format name="en_US" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Price/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#,###.##', ../../Format)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (wrapped into a top element node to be made well-formed):

```
<t>
    <Details>
        <Order>Bulk Order</Order>
        <OrderDate>1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00</OrderDate>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
        <Price>1199.45</Price>
        <Format>de_DE</Format>
    </Details>
    <Details>
        <Order>Bulk Order</Order>
        <OrderDate>1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00</OrderDate>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
        <Price>1199.45</Price>
        <Format>en_US</Format>
    </Details>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<t>
    <Details>
        <Order>Bulk Order</Order>
        <OrderDate>1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00</OrderDate>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
        <Price>1,199.45</Price>
        <Format>de_DE</Format>
    </Details>
    <Details>
        <Order>Bulk Order</Order>
        <OrderDate>1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00</OrderDate>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>
        <Price>1199,45</Price>
        <Format>en_US</Format>
    </Details>
</t>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're in a template match for 'Details' nodes then you could do something like this:

```
<xslt:choose> 
    <xslt:when test="Format/text() = 'de_DE'"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(Price, '###,###.00')" /></xslt:when> 
    <xslt:when test="Format/text() = 'en_US'"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(Price, '###.###,00')" /></xslt:when> 
    <xslt:otherwise><xsl:value-of select='format-number(Price, "###.###,00")' /></xslt:otherwise> 
</xslt:choose>
```

$format is for when you have a variable named 'format' defined by *<xslt:variable/>*.  The test condition accepts XPath statements like Format (node child of Details) / text() (the text child node of Format)